# How to cite same author but different articles in a compact way? (biblatex, biber, APA)

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style

In my document I use `biblatex` with `biber` as a backend and the APA style. Now, I have two different articles by the same author and would like to cite them such that the output is:

Author (year_x, year_y) and not Author (year_x), Author (year_y)

which is what:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{~/Documents/Library.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}

\title{Question}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\textcites{<key>}{<key>}


\end{document}
```

gives me. What is the most convenient way to get the desired result?

Comment: `\textcite{<key1>,<key2>}`, but then you can't have pre- and postnotes for both of them.

Comment: What do you mean by pre- and postnotes, though? I guess it is related to adding pages to each citation because that now only works for the latter of the two citations. What is the best way to achieve my desired output still allowing me to add pages to each entry?

Comment: Indeed, you can have `\textcites[7]{<key1>}[8]{<key2>}` but you can't do the same thing with `\textcite{<key1>,<key2>}`, the postnote will always stick to the end. The standard style `style=authoryear-comp` gives a slightly nicer output, I will see if I can convince `biblatex-apa` to do the same. (Double check if this complies with APA style guidelines.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\textcite{<key1>,<key2>}
```

but as mentioned in the comments this can't deal with multiple pre- and postnotes.

The standard style `style=authoryear-comp` also give good output with

```
\textcites[34-37]{<key1>}[78-79]{<key2>}
```

and you should be able to get the same with `biblatex-apa` if you apply the following tweaks

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
  \usebibmacro{postnote}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{multicitecount}=\value{multicitetotal}}
    {\setunit{}%
     \printtext{%
       \ifbool{cbx:parens}
         {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
         {}}}
    {\setunit{%
       \ifbool{cbx:parens}
         {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
         {}%
       \textcitedelim}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:init}{%
  \ifnumless{\value{multicitecount}}{2}
    {\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}%
     \global\undef\cbx@lasthash}
    {\iffieldundef{prenote}
       {}
       {\global\undef\cbx@lasthash}}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\textcites}{\textcite}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\textcites[7]{knuth:ct:a}[8]{knuth:ct:b}

\textcites[7]{knuth:ct:a}[8]{sigfridsson}

\textcites{sigfridsson}

\textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you think this is a feature the style should have (especially if you can point to a rule in the APA style guide that requires this), please open a feature request at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues

Comment: Thank you very much for your help - it works as desired. I will have a look what the APA style guide says with regard to this issue.

Comment: Sorry for coming back to this. How should I adapt your macros such that `\textcites[7]{knuth:ct:a}[8]{knuth:ct:b}` gives Knuth (1984, p.7; 1986, p. 8)? I am asking because the comma can become misleading in the case of `\textcites[7]{knuth:ct:a}{knuth:ct:b}` which would give (1984, p.7, 1986).

Comment: @apitsch On first glance that looks a bit more tricky, please ask a new question about it, maybe someone else can step in, or I can have a look later. BTW: Did you double check with your APA manual? Is this a requirement that should be reported to the `biblatex-apa` developer?

Comment: regarding the APA style guide: My resource is the German book "Lern- und Arbeitsstrategien" by Christoph Metzger which for the case of quoting several works by the same author according to APA recommends to cite them as follows: (Author, year of first publication, year of second publication) or Author (year of first publication, year of second publication). However this is not the official style guide.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any guidelines for the case of citing two works of the same author one of which with a page reference. I do not know whether the works should be separated by a comma or a colon in this case.

Comment: \textcite{<key1>,<key2>} just gives one parenthesis like Gurley and Shaw (1955), 1966 for me instead of Gurley and Shaw (1955, 1966). I am using biblatex-aer  (https://github.com/dmsul/biblatex-aer) which builds upon biblatex-chicago.

Comment: @Hazards I would consider that a bug in the style that you should report to the style author. The standard `-comp` styles should give what I would intuitively call the 'correct' result 'Gurley and Shaw (1955, 1966)' here.

Comment: @moewe It has to do with `\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}} )
    or
    ( not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} )
  }
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
    {}%
  \printtext[textcitehyperref]{%
   \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
    \usebibmacro{textcite}}}`
When I comment out this part, hyperref does not longer "recognize" the authors anymore (just colors the date). Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Hazards I suggest you ask a new question about that if you need help. It is always a bit awkward to wield long blocks of code in the comments.

Comment: @moewe Fair enough, I will do it. Thanks anyway!