# How to get combined authors citations with biblatex apa package?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am using the `biblatex-apa` package. However, I would like to get citation with combined authors, like

> Doe (2017, 2018)

rather than

> Doe (2017) and Doe (2018).

I checked the `biblatex-apa` documentation but couldn't find it.

Comment: Works for me: `\textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:e}`. Please show us a short example document that reproduces the issue. Make sure that the example document contains all information necessary to reproduce the issue and can be run in an empty folder with only the files provided in the question (in particular you must include two example `.bib` entries or use `biblatex-examples.bib`). See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864

Comment: @moewe Thanks. Good to know that it should work. I haven't figured out why it does not in my document and haven't managed to create a short example either.

Comment: Does it work if you cite `\textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:e}` from `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}` (that file is installed on your system and will be found automatically) in your document? Do things work if you start from a very small document? There are two ways to produce an MWE: Start with an empty file and add enough code from the problematic document until the error occurs or start from (a copy of) the entire document and remove stuff until the problem occurs.

Comment: @moewe Yes, it works with a new document. However, the one I am working with actually is several different documents but I'll try to cut it down.

Comment: In theory there is little that could cause this: My number one guess would be to try the two offending entries in a new empty document. For an MWE you can easily remove all text of the document and most stuff in the preamble should not be relevant.

Comment: @moewe Okay, I think I found the problem. I am actually using LyX and when I reorder authors it changes from the `\textcite`  to `\textcites` for no good reason. I'll report it as a bug then. Thanks again.

Comment: Tracked at https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compact citations work fine if all entries are given within the same pair of curly braces of a `\cite` command

```
\textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:e}
```

As it turns out LyX (not entirely unreasonably) would turn this citation into a multicite command in certain situations (e.g. upon reordering of the citations)

```
\textcites{knuth:ct:a}{knuth:ct:e}
```

See https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11308. Note that it absolutely makes sense to use a multi-cite command if there are post- and pre-notes involved, since those have to stick to the respective entries. The behaviour for empty pre- and postnote is going to be changed, though.

The problem then is that `biblatex-apa` does not give compact citations across several multi-cite braces. Compare

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:e}

\textcites{knuth:ct:a}{knuth:ct:e}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Knuth (1984, 1986)//Knuth (1984), Knuth (1986)]

`biblatex-apa` can be convinced to give slightly nicer output in some cases as explained in [How to cite same author but different articles in a compact way? (biblatex, biber, APA)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442504/35864).